# Delegation question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

### code structure

```
@protocal A_Delegate
{
     -(void)doIt:(BOOL)isDone;
}

Super Class A // has properties of set delegate
-(void) setDelegate:(id<A_Delegate>)_delegate
{
       /*self.delegate = _delegate*/ error, compiler stops right there and doesn't assigns the value from '_delegate'
```

<strike>self.delegate = _delegate</strike>.

```
       //should be
       delegate = _delegate;
}

Sub Class B : A // want to call and define the delegation for the super class of B which is A
-(void) acquireDelegation:(id<A_Delegate>)_delegate
{
       [[super delegate] setDelegate];
}
```

Now, the Class C want to use the Class B and want to know its state,

```
Class C : NSObject <A_Delegation>
-(void) doSomething
{
     B *b = [[B alloc]init];
     [b aquireDelegation:self];
}
-(void)doIt:(BOOL)isDone
{
      if(isDone)
      // Do Something
}
```

Does any body know What I have done wrong and why super can't delegation?
Is it possible to fix?

resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would lead to infinite loop (until the stack overflow):

```
-(void) setDelegate:(id<A_Delegate>)_delegate
{
       self.delegate = _delegate; // error, compiler stops right there and doesn't assigns the value from '_delegate'
}
```

cause `self.delegate = _delegate;` is calling `setDelegate:`. You have to assign to the ivar itself.

And I think this is not compiler. It is everything in runtime...

Comment: Any Idea How to modify to assign in super class without infinite loop? Please help.

Comment: what is the delegate's ivar? how did you declare it in @interface? if it is delegate, then just delegate = _delegate; OR just delete this method - it is redundant if you synthesize the delegate

Comment: oh that was dumb mistake. i was confused with self and super, thank you for your help. ; )

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues.  First, that protocol definition, well, isn't one.  The syntax is all wrong.  Secondly, what is "Super Class A" is that meant to be a comment?

Anyhoo, the major problem is in the setDelegate: method.  If you have defined the delegate property then the line:

```
self.delegate = _delegate;
```

is equal to the line:

```
[self setDelegate:_delegate];
```

So, in the method -setDelegate you are calling -setDelegate.

Comment: do you even know what the super and sub class is ? please.